# Solution to trigger the middleware when updating of a subdocument

Tags: mongoose, updates, middleware

I use this schema of addresses and use it in several schemas.
All works fine, only when I update a address

```js
const addressSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    street: String,
    number: String,
    postcode: String,
    city: String,
    comment: String,
    country: {
        type: 'ObjectId',
        ref: 'Country'
    },
    location: {
        type: pointSchema,
        default: () => ({}),
        index: '2dsphere',
    }
});

addressSchema.pre('save', async function (next) {
    console.log('subdocument address pre.save'); // is triggred
    //create geolocation
});


addressSchema.pre('updateOne', async function (next) {
    console.log('subdocument address pre.updateOne'); // not triggred, no error
    //update geolocation
});
```

Mongoose's documation speak only about middelware save and validate.

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html#what-is-a-subdocument-

But what is the best solution to do what I want ?

---

**Additional informations**

```js
const pointSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    type: {
        type: String,
        enum: ['Point'],
        default: 'Point'
    },
    coordinates: {
        type: [Number],
        default: null,
    }
});
```

```js
const common = require('./common');
const customerSchema = new Schema({
    //...
   address: {
        type: common.addressSchema,
        default: () => ({}),
    },
})

const providerSchema = new Schema({
    //...
   address: {
        type: common.addressSchema,
        default: () => ({}),
    },
})
```

```json
    "address": {
        "_id": "6043a5f3a8cad615cd8eab3a",
        "location": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                48.818511962890625,
                2.31961989402771
            ],
            "_id": "603fed0629390b30d53bed3e"
        },
        "street": "Avenue des Tulipes",
        "postcode": "78500",
        "number": "69",
        "city": "Montrouge",
        "comment": null,
        "country": "5f626eb337fd4d75ab694112"
    },
```

When we create a new customer we have no problem with addressSchema's middleware 'save', but when we update a Customer, all datas are updated correctly, but the addressSchema's middleware 'updateOne' isn't triggered.

Comment: can you post pointSchema and your update query that is not triggering in middleware.

Comment: is this address schema, child of customer schema? if it is then please specify in your question. and also it will helpful if you post your update query as well.

Comment: it's a child of several schemas, it's used for each schema wich have addresse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure is there any straight way to do this, but you can create pre midddlewares for your all parent schemas `customerSchema` and `providerSchema` and put condition like is address updated or not,

- create a function to handle operation on address schema if its in update

```
function preHookForAddress (_this) {
   // if its "address" object
   if (_this.get('address')) {
        let address = _this.get('address');
        // operation stuff here
        // ..
        // set after update
        _this.set({ address: address });
   }

   // if its "address.location" object
   if (_this.get('address.location')) {
        let address_location = _this.get('address.location');
        // operation stuff here
        // ..
        // set after update
        _this.set({ "address.location": address_location });
   }
}

customerSchema.pre('updateOne', async function (next) {
    await preHookForAddress(this);
    next();
});

providerSchema.pre('updateOne', async function (next) {
    await preHookForAddress(this);
    next();
});
```